# hp 4500 stopped working not installed. after an update

Tags: drivers

Using Ubuntu 16.04LTS printer stopped working. I think it was after an update.Will not give me a way to install the printer. the add button can not click it.If i try to continue it says no server.

Comment: did you have `hplip` prior to the update ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update HPLIP in ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985024/how-to-update-hplip-in-ubuntu-16-04) and [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1137815/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like problem with `cups`. What is status of cups - `sudo systemctl status org.cups.cupsd`? If it's just stopped, then `sudo systemctl start org.cups.cupsd` and if you want it running after boot then `sudo systemctl enable org.cups.cupsd`.