# Hp Scanner and printer is not working despite installing hplip

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, scanner

My question is different as I already employ the method installing the driver as mentioned in the above link. Still it didn't work. So it is not the duplicate as I asked it after utilizing the available proposed solution.

I have a Laserjet N1212nf MFP, which is all in one. I have hplip version 3.18.9, yet I cannot scan or print. I tried scanning the document by simple scan. I got the error similar to ot.

```
Failed to open device `hpaio:/usb/,....': Error during device I/O
```

I tried hp-doctor and hp-toolbox, now simple scan detects the scanner correctly. However, when click for scanning, the message pops up unable to connect to scanner.

With xscan, similar error with message device busy.

```
Failed to open device
`hpaio:/usb/HP_Laserjet_Professional_M1212nf_MFP?serial000000000QJ87YFCPRa':
Device busy
```

The printer name with fax is being detected by document viewer.

What should I do now. Should I uninstall it and re-install again?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the steps you used for installing the printer?

Comment: I downloaded the hplip debian file from hp website; and then run with sh command. Later on I run hp-setup. The printer didn't get setup so I run hp-doctor. While running it, it turns out that it can't access ppd file. To give the access I run chmod command. After I also download hp-toolbox. I also run "sudo apt install sni-qt"

Comment: Consider to remove binary hplip and install hplip from the repository (see [*Uninstallation* section in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509)). Your device needs it with HPLIP >=3.10.4 ([see hplip site](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index)). So it is possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) .

Comment: From your comment, the printer isn't installed.  Follow the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/985045/29012).  Since you have already installed the HP software, proceed from the section **Manually adding the printer**.

Comment: After manually adding the printer, now I can print the pdf files. Still I can't scan. Bit busy, but I would now try the N0rbet's suggestion.