# How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, scanner, hplip

Let's assume that one has some HP printer and/or scanner and checked its support status on the corresponding page of HPLIP site - [*HP Developer Portal | All Supported Printer Models*](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).

So one have the following information: the device *Model name*, *Min. HPLIP
Version* and *Driver Plug-in* need.

What should one install to make Ubuntu fully support the HP printer and/or scanner?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently Ubuntu have [the following HPLIP versions in *universe* pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=hplip-gui):

> ```
> bionic (18.04LTS): 3.17.10+repack0-5
> focal (20.04LTS): 3.20.3+dfsg0-2
> hirsute (21.04): 3.21.2+dfsg1-2
> impish (21.10): 3.21.6+dfsg0-0ubuntu1
> ```

This leads to the following variants.

## HPLIP installation

### (a) Required HPLIP version ≤ repository HPLIP version

So if one sees that *Min. HPLIP
Version* is lower or equal to the version of the HPLIP package from repository, then the installation of the following packages will be enough with:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui
```

### (b) Required HPLIP version > repository HPLIP version

If one sees that *Min. HPLIP
Version* is greater than the version of the HPLIP package from repository, then one needs to install binary HPLIP by following [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509).

## (o) Optional HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver

If one sees that *Driver Plug-in* is set to *yes* (or *required*), then one needs to install the binary/proprietary plugin/driver by following [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070471/66509).

---

Examples for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (hplip 3.17.10) and some HP device models:

| **Model Name** | **Min. HPLIP Version** | **Driver Plug-in** | **Action** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP LaserJet 6l Printer | 0.9.5 | No | (a) |
| HP LaserJet Pro MFP m426fdn | 3.15.11 | Required | (a)+(o) |
| HP Tango | 3.18.12 | No | (b) |
| HP PageWide MFP 774dn | 3.18.9 | yes | (b)+(o) |