# Printing and Ubuntu 18

Tags: sound, printing, hp

Ubuntu cannot find my HP 2130 printer, which was automatically installed in the previous Ubuntu release and ran without a problem. Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't install the printer automatically, and it doesn't give me the option to do it manually. Same as with sound. No search facility to find the printer.

I clicked in *Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Printers*, but the operating system displays `Sorry the system printing service doesn't seem to be available.` No Add button. I never had a problem with previous releases of Ubuntu, with printing, scanning and sound. Since I loaded Ubuntu 18 right from the beginning, and if I want to print or scan I have to use my Windows laptop.

Comment: this is not how one asks for help from people,please edit your question and remove the rubbish.

Comment: You're right, they changed the package for HP printers in Ubuntu 18.04. Please read the accepted answer to this question: [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/). Then download and install the binary from HP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) . For your printer you need HPLIP >=3.15.6 and of course `cups`. Follow solution *(a)* in the answer.