# Should I remove the HPlip packages from the Ubuntu repositories before installing the latest version with the HP provided .run installer?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, hplip

I need the latest version of HPLip on my computer to fully support a new printer. I already have HPLip and HPLip GUI installed from the Ubuntu repositories. HP offers a .run based installer to be run in bash. Should I remove the HPLip deb packages before I run the HP installer, or will the HP installer update current version? I am afraid to just try since I may mess up the printer sub system not knowing how to fix it.

Comment: Whilst the current convention is to remove old versions of HPLIP, I installed a newer version and in the installation process, it asked if I wanted to remove the old one which I accepted and it worked without further issue.

Comment: You are right, it asked to remove the current driver and everything went well. The only thing I noticed is that the HP Device Manager "hp-toolbox" takes around 20 seconds to open. It used to be pretty instant. Adding printers works without problems and since I am not using the Device Manager much it doesn't matter. Would be insteresting to know why it takes so long though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing the packages provided by Ubuntu if you're about to replace them with a more recent version from the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the current convention is to remove old versions of HPLIP, I installed a newer version and in the installation process, it asked if I wanted to remove the old one which I accepted and it worked without further issue.