# hp laserjet 600-M602 in pause

Tags: 16.04, printing, hp

I am trying to print a file but the printer does not work in the dialog that opens when printing it says the printer is in pause, and nothing happens.

The printer  is a the office hp laserjet 600-M602

I use ubuntu 16.04 and I am connected to the local net with a LAN

The printer has always worked for me until today.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - install `hplip-gui` package from the repository.

Comment: @N0rbert I have installed the package: what should I do now?

Comment: Run `hp-setup` and follow instructions.