# ubuntu 20.04 missing dependencies

Tags: dependencies

Attempting to install hplip-3.20.3.run on Ubuntu 20.04

```
missing dependencies:
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional   
pil                  scan                 OPTIONAL            
pyqt4-dbus           gui_qt4              REQUIRED            
reportlab            fax                  OPTIONAL            
pyqt4                gui_qt4              REQUIRED            
python-notify        gui_qt4              OPTIONAL


Unable to find dependent files.
Install aborted.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - carefully check this starting from printer model. You may not need binary HPLIP installer at all.

Comment: FYI the bug was previously reported on launchpad as https://pad.lv/1876205 . Workaround is to use `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`.

Comment: I tried that. Since I have a wifi connected printer (HP 5740) I needed to connect a USB cable for the setup. For some reason, setup doesn't/didn't recognize the USB port, even though I use both frequently with no issues.

Comment: I was able to work around the problem. I checked the IP address of my printer (192.168.xx.xx) and ran "hp-setup 192.168.xx.xx" actual numbers used. It worked perfectly and now I can print and scan with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround. Use the following command (192.168.xx.xx is my printers IP address)

```
hp-setup 192.168.xx.xx
```