# HP PRINTER/SCANNER

Tags: 18.04, usb, hp

I bought HP Laser MFP 135a black and white scanner/printer. I am new in Ubuntu and I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I tried to open localhost:631 by installing CUPS in Terminal as seeing in one youtube video but no suceed. I do not know much to do. I use printer/scanner via USB. Could someone be kind and help me to set to work both scanner and printer.

```
:~$ lsusb -t 
/: Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M 
/: Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/11p, 480M 
|__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Printer, Driver=usblp, 480M 
|__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M 
/: Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M 
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
|__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M 
|__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M 
|__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M 
|__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M 
|__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M 
|__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M 
|__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M 
|__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - use `sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui`, then `hp-setup` followed by `hp-plugin` .

Comment: does the scanner/printer state that is supported on linux? Try doing the following: -Open Settings -Go to printer and press add The printer should be detected. Try using chrrome to print or libre office. Also do you have scanner software installed?

Comment: The USB cable maybe faulty. Please replug it and show the output of `lsusb -t` - add it to the question.

Comment: |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M

Comment: Also I could not copy to terminal you sent hp-plugin. There werent nowere to paste it in Terminal altought i tried

Comment: Please don't put the terminal output in the comments. It is best to put all additional information directly into the question using the [edit question link above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1253725/edit). When you copy and paste any output from the terminal into your question please format them as `code` using the { } icon above the **Edit Question** window.

Answer (score 0):

You need `sane-airscan`. Refer page https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan/blob/master/README.md

You need to follow detail & steps mentioned in [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=314966) and further in [this](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Apzz&package=sane-airscan) post by selecting your operation system Ubuntu 18.04.

1. Add repository

   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositori ... ntu_18.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:pzz.list"
2. Download key key

   wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositor ... elease.key -O Release.key
3. Add key

   sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
4. update repositories

   sudo apt-get update
5. install sane-airscan

   sudo apt-get install sane-airscan