# Ubuntu 20.04 Printer "Choose Driver" - "Change Driver" List Not Displaying

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, hp

I have just updated to Ubuntu 20.04.  The list of options for "Printers" "Choose Driver" "Change Driver" list isn't displaying like it did in Ubuntu 18.04.  This displays indefinitely.

[image]

I have tried to resolve this without success by adding these 3 repositories:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

What I'm expecting is a list of printer manufacturers (including Brother, Canon, HP) and then the ability to select printer models under the manufacturer.

What I'm actually trying to install is **HP LaserJet 1012** with driver STP02205.PPD .  I am not finding this driver file online.  This was on the available list in **Ubuntu 18.04**.

When I try

```
sudo  apt-get --reinstall install hplip hplip-gui
```

and then run

```
sudo ./hplip-3.20.6.run
```

the script becomes stuck at:

```
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
Would you like to retry installing the missing package(s)
```

I have already added the repository `universe`

I am unsure if `hplip-3.20.6.run` is wanting to use **Python 2.7** (Now at end of life) or **Python 3**.

The script `hplip-3.20.6.run` ends running with the message:

```
RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------
error: A required dependency 'pyqt5 (PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
```

I also wanted to share the [results](https://pastebin.com/ZARSvWYF) of `pip3 search pyqt5`.  I don't know what I am suppose to be installing.

Additionally I am unable to install optional dependencies:

```
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100

Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-notify'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100

Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-reportlab'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
```

What confounds me even more is that I'm receiving these same errors on a fresh install of `Ubuntu Studio 20.04`.  This makes me wonder if `hplip-3.20.6.run` has been tested and tweaked for use in the latest LTS release of Ubuntu.

I edited my [/etc/apt/sources.list](https://pastebin.com/tuK3f11C) with **ca.archive.ubuntu.com** becoming **archive.ubuntu.com** .

The command [sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade](https://pastebin.com/VUymbNDH) did not have any errors when refreshing and no software updates.

This did not make a difference when I reached the **DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION** step in `hplip-3.20.6.run`

```
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100

Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100

Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-notify'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100

Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-reportlab'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
```

The script ended with

```
RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------
error: A required dependency 'pyqt5 (PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
```

The reason I used `sudo ./hplip-3.20.6.run` is on account of the [600+ permissions related errors](https://pastebin.com/K2yWvJE5) caused without **sudo**

Using `hp-setup` puts me right back at the error I've described above:

```
rpiggott@rpiggott-Aspire-5742Z:~/Downloads$ hp-setup

Command 'hp-setup' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install hplip

rpiggott@rpiggott-Aspire-5742Z:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install hplip
[sudo] password for rpiggott: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
hplip is already the newest version (3.20.3+dfsg0-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Trying to [uninstall and re-install](https://pastebin.com/uSGNJhKf) left me with the error

```
Can't open /etc/hp/hplip.conf: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - use `sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui` followed by `hp-setup` .

Comment: No. I get to 'Missing Dependencies' and it can't get **python-pyqt5** to install

Comment: Run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and retry.

Comment: I already did this step **'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.**

Comment: I've also tried starting fresh again **sudo  apt-get --reinstall install hplip hplip-gui**

Comment: As for me, you have wrong repositories. Please share the output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` command to the question body or to pastebin.

Comment: this is definitely a bug in ubuntu 20.04,this problem does not exist in previous versions of ubuntu,i wonder if anybody has managed to install a hp printer in 20.04?

Comment: @N0rbert I have amended my question with the repository list

Comment: @trondhansen I've just started completing the contact form for hp's developers to inquire if I've come across a Ubuntu 20.04 bug.

Comment: I will recommend swicthing to main server using `software-properties-gtk` or using text editor (change `ca.archive.ubuntu.com` to `archive.ubuntu.com`) and then ensure that you do not have any errors while executing `sudo apt update` . And finally retry HPLIP installation.

Comment: the printer stopped funktioning when i updated from 19.10 to 20.04

Comment: @N0rbert changing to **archive.ubuntu.com** followed by **sudo apt update** and then re-running **hplip-3.20.6.run** has not resolved the problem.  I have updated my question (above) with the output so it is all in one place.

Comment: Actually you do not need to run `sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui` and `sudo ./hplip-3.20.6.run` at the same time. I would recommend to choose deb-package based solution. Simply run `hp-setup`.

Comment: @N0rbert I updated my post with the results of not using **sudo**.  This puts me right back where I am at with the present error.

Comment: I can't understand how and why you got stuck. The simple `sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui` followed by `hp-setup` should simply work. I do not have HP device and 20.04 LTS near me, but it should work. The binary installer (*hplip-3.20.6.run*) is not needed at all for such an old device. If it is half installed - remove it by following uninstallation part of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert This hasn't gone smoothly either.  I've updated the question with a link to my pastebin account.

Comment: @N0rbert I also get the same error on my fresh install with Ubuntu Studio 20.04 .  (What we've been dealing with was as an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04)  I'd have to conclude there is a bug somewhere in `hplip` that isn't compatible with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Amazingly I got it working based on the answer you referenced ( https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/453336 )

Comment: @trondhansen See my answer (below) of steps that resolved this problem

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of not being able to install my **HP LaserJet 1012** printer was a partial install using the [binary](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing) and not what is supplied through Ubuntu.

Step 1: Purge existing HP software from the binary

```
sudo apt-get purge hplip hplip-data hplip-doc hplip-gui hpijs-ppds libsane-hpaio printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
```

Step 2: Remove directory (if it exists)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip/
```

Step 3: Remove packages no longer required

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Step 4:  Install the HP graphical user interface:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Step 5: With Ubuntu 20.04 graphic interface local HP LIP tool and follow the prompts accordingly to add your HP printer.

This answer is based on a previous [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) post.

Comment: this did not solve my problem,my printer is HP envy 4520 i can install it with your solution and the printer is detected.everything looks fine until i try to print a page then i get a no comunication error.in ubuntu 16.04-17.04-18.04-19.04 there is no problem and the usb ports are funktioning with every other thing i connect.thank you for your answer but sadly it does not fix the problem in ubuntu 20.04 for me.

Comment: I actually also have an HP Envy Photo 7855 printer.  I will try to install it and see how it goes and get back to you.  However if there is a problem I did make an inroad with HP Linux developers support.  We can reach out to them if needed.  Try not to be disheartened.

Comment: there is 7 pages related to printers for 20.04 here on ask and very few have been solved,after having used ubuntu for 11years i have come to expect the possibility to print a few pages a year.it should not be needed for the many printer manufactorers to solve a problem that ubuntu has created(sorry if this sounds like a rant but it is frustrating to have to send all my dokuments to an other pc with a lower version number of ubuntu simply to print a simple dokument)

Comment: How do you connect your printer?  USB?  Ethernet?  Wireless?

Comment: i use usb and when i used hplip to install it was installed with usb and detected fine,i even managed to print one page but at the next reboot of my pc the no com problem returned.

Comment: i have now installed the printer HP ENVY 4520 on my wifi network and it is funktioning so far.so for me the solution was to install the printer in wifi mode.i installed it from the menu on the printer so i did not need to touch my pc at all.it does not show in HPLIP menu but it works.

Comment: @trondhansen Then it seems your best course of action is creating a report at: https://launchpad.net/hplip/+addquestion to sort out what has gone wrong.

Comment: @trondhansen I am glad you got this sorted.