# Ubuntu 20.04 hplip needs pyqt4, which is not available anymore

Tags: package-management, printing, hp, hplip

I know this has been asked before, but the solutions did not work for me.

I have an **HP OfficeJet Pro 8625**, which worked fine under 18.04.  HPLIP does not install properly because of a dependency that is no longer available.  Specifically, it needs `python3-pyqt4` which has been removed from the repositories.  Earlier questions suggested steps that do not work for this printer.

I added `hplip-gui` and still no-go. I downloaded the install script from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing, and the install script will not complete.
I did `cd ~/Downloads/hplip-3.20.6`, then `./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-qt5 --disable-qt-4`, then `make`, then `sudo make install`. These all seemed to complete. But I still cannot use the printer.  I only run LTR's because it is such a pain to go thru this every 6 months. Even every 2 years is hard. My printer is not working.

any ideas, other than reverting to 18.04 until this gets fixed?

Comment: did you try in Settings -> Printer -> Add.. to configure your printer or Additional Printer Settings ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - really you needs >3.14.4, so `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` would be enough.

Comment: "The solutions did not work" does not provide any useful information for us to help you. It doesn't show how your problem is different. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258955/) to show us complete output demonstrating that you followed the instructions correctly and showing the complete error.

Comment: Keep in mind that if HPLIP doesn't work, then that's something HP has to fix, not Ubuntu.  (This is not really an answer but more of a "hey, tell HP to fix their software" thing.)