# Need drivers to install HP deskjet 3630

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

Is it necessary to download drivers to install a new HP Deskjet 3630 printer on a pc running Ubuntu?

Comment: No drivers required with most printers. Ubuntu now users driverless printing. Or are you running a real old version of Ubuntu?  And both of my HP printers just worked. If issues: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - `sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a HP printer.  When I go to the HP web site and search for drivers/software, the site will (normally) ask for the specific product I own, then for the specific model number of that product, then for the operating system on my computer.  At that point, my browser is redirected and the new page where the instructions are simply to download and install a given file (the file is on the page and is of a type that would run under Linux), make sure the printer is turned on and print a test page.  And you are set.  Now, I just hope that HP does not stop making the printer cartridges for my printer any time soon.  I really do not want to go through the trouble of finding and getting used to a new printer.