# installing non-postcript printer

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, cups-lpd

I want to install a HP DesignJet Z6100 (not Z6100PS) on Ubuntu 20.04

The driver provided by hplip is for the postscript version of the printer: Z6100PS.
If I use it, the printer replies "error 61:01 - wrong file format". Probably the driver sends postscript data.

I tried to install a ppd file I found online at the University of Delaware.
Now the printer shows up as "DesignJet Z6100" (not Z6100PS), but trying to print I get the same error.

According to wikipedia a ppd should show up here `/usr/share/ppd/` or there `/usr/share/cups/model/`
but there is nothing new.

Wikipedia also states

> CUPS uses PPD drivers for all of its PostScript printers, and has even extended the concept to allow for PostScript printing to non-PostScript printing devices, by directing output through a CUPS filter.

So I figured it might be possible to use that printer on Linux even if there is no driver.
Is it?
How do you make a ppd?
Anything concerning groups and permissions? (user is in lpadmin)

what I also tried:

`lpinfo -v:` does see it:

network dnssd://HP%20Designjet%20Z6100%2042in%20Photo%20%5B9D6B69%5D._pdl-datastream._tcp.local

I can access the printer via the web interface.

But: HP Device Manager doesn't detect it via Ethernet.
Printer has no USB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Checked it thoroughly, followed all steps. hplip is installed. The driver seems to be for postscript variants only, as with all the DesignJets in the Z-series.