# The HP DeskJet 2622 wont print with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, hp

I have a not very old HP DeskJet 2622 printer connected with a USB connection. I have not been able to print anything with 20.04 ubuntu.  I had no problem printing with 18.04.  Is my printer incompatible with 20.04.  If yes then what HP printers will work with 20.04.  I setup my printer with hp-setup but error messages say no communication (error 5012) with the printer. Another message was about HP and no system tray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner). You need at least 3.17.7, so installing hplip-gui package would be enough.

Comment: Your printer is fully supported natively on 20.04 without the need for HPLIP. See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting.