# HP LaserJet Pro M1132 Multifunction Printer on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, hp

I would like to use the HP LaserJet Pro M1132 Multifunction Printer on Ubuntu 20.04, however it seems that the latest drivers are for Ubuntu 12.04 (see here: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_professional_m1132_mfp), so it doesn't print.

I wondered if it is possible just to use the Ubuntu 12.04 drivers, but through the hp-setup utility it just stalls for ever, and so has no results.

Is there a way to get my printer going?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - install `hplip-gui`, then run `hp-plugin`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above you could couse `cups` with egs.`hplib` to get your printer running. you can access `cups` via your browser via `localhost:631`. You need to enter your current username and password.
For the infos required by cups its normally the easiest, if you just go to your printer and search for your (network)printer settings and print them out.

Openprinting
https://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP
alternativly lists a second free driver for your M1132
https://www.openprinting.org/driver/foo2xqx
you can download the driver directly from their project page. Installation guide is provided.
http://foo2xqx.rkkda.com/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I solved my problem using ghostscript-printer-app on Ubuntu 22