# Duplex printing no longer works, and blank pages print before each job

Tags: printing, hp, 20.10

I have an HP Officejet Pro 8620 and when printing from Ubuntu it has recently started to put out a blank page before each print job and it will no longer print duplex (both sides of the page). When printing the second page it is also upside-down from the first.
The settings for duplex are set properly in the Ubuntu print settings when printing.  Not seeing any errors in the OS and everything works normally from a Windows 10 PC.  So far my research and troubleshooting has turned up nothing, not sure where to go from here on finding the issue.

Comment: "The settings for duplex are set properly in the Ubuntu print settings when printing." please [edit] your question to indicate what settings you have set.

Comment: System settings -> printer -> printer options -> page setup:
Pages per side: 1
Two Sided: Long Edge (Standard)

Settings are also set properly in the individual jobs sent from any application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner), so `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` would be ok.

Comment: Not knowing the type of connection you have and the Ubuntu version you are using is a drawback. Read and absorb [the advice here](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSQuickPrintQueues).

Comment: Installing the hplip-gui, installing the printer through that, then enabling the duplex feature (option that did not appear before) did the trick.   For reference this is Ubuntu 20.10 printing over network.