# HP Printer error: “IllegalOperatorSequence”

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, printing, libreoffice

I have an HP LaserJet 1320, and Lubuntu 20.04 on an old Macmini. Since I installed Lubuntu 18 packagewise over Ubuntu upgraded from 16, I have been encountering a printer error. ** I have since completely wiped and reinstalled Lubuntu, using only default printing software.**

Sometimes, particularly when copying text from webpages into LibreOffice, my printer prints these two pages instead of whatever was requested.

[image: error pages]

Since wiping the entire OS, I think it’s been working better, but sometimes this still happens. Occasionally, other things will happen such as the page having the right borders and tables and stuff, but it looks like between libreoffice and the printer there was an encoding mistake, and several characters are replaced with gibberish symbols.

Why is this happening now, and how can I fix it? I am almost certain it is because of ghost characters, since if I paste to and print from featherpad, the problem disappears. But why was it working before and not currently?

…Is there a way I can remove these ghost characters without losing special formatting?

Edit: as per comment, I installed hplip and it’s GUI, but I am still encountering the problem. HPLIP was apparently involved in the job (see image).
[image: print status]
I even exported to PDF and printed from the HPLIP GUI directly, but with the same error. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Comment: @N0rbert Maybe so. Thanks, I’ll check it out.

Comment: @N0rbert question updated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually running.  You mention Lubuntu 18 (no such release as *yy* format releases are *snap* only and Lubuntu is *deb* based so do you mean 18.04) which to me is a concern. The release  notices said things can break so re-install was the only supported method to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. The 16 & 18 refs just confuse me (and are potential troubles due to desktop change).

Comment: @guiverc I am sorry that was so confusing. What I was trying to say was that I originally had Ubuntu 16, then I upgraded to Ubuntu 18, installed lubuntu-desktop via apt, upgraded to lubuntu 20, then wiped and fresh installed lubuntu 20.

Comment: @guiverc I mentioned all three, because I’m pretty sure the problem occurred after I had ubuntu 20, fresh or otherwise.

Comment: How does Ubuntu Core 20 relate? Lubuntu is a *deb* based release, and not snap based so uses the *year.month* format and has never had a snap only 20 release. Ubuntu has used the *yy* format for different products since 2016; no flavor provides support for them.. they are smaller lighter and less powerful release intended for *headless* devices, but the reduced size also made them useful in cloud too .  I'd suggest sticking to the *deb* based *year.month* releases.

Comment: @guiverc I always used XX.04 of everything.