# printer HP 1050 does not work with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hp

The HP 1050 printer is connected locally to a Windows 10 PC and shared on the network. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an older laptop and wanted to share this printer with no luck. I have installed HPLIP and CUPS. Cups recognizes the printer but when I try to print I get a message that the printer may not be connected. Cups forces port 9100 to be used, but is not used in Win 10. Hplip does not recognize the printer. I am a linux novice, please help me on how to solve this problem.
WojtekS

Comment: is that still the case if you fully close Win10 ie to perform a full shutdown, simply hold down the SHIFT key on your keyboard and then click the “Shut down” option in the Start Menu, or on the sign-in screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) – installation of `hplip-gui` deb-package should fix the issue.

Comment: The printer does not print regardless of how the windows are closed and the firewall is turned off or on. Of course, I also installed the HP GUI with no luck. I always get the message printer is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

20.04 can find the printer and install. It could not connect to the printer until I disconnected my VPN.  Maybe that helps.