# HPLIP cannot install on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: hp

I recently install Ubuntu and really need my HP Deskjet 2130 series drivers.

I went to the HPLIP official website and downloaded the drivers, followed the instructions, executed the `.run` file, followed some more instructions and then it asked me to download some missing dependencies (most of which had "python"). I let the installer do its thing. Then it said it failed to download the missing dependencies, so I am unable to install HPLIP until this is fixed.

[image: Screen shot of errors]

Comment: According to HP's [HPLIP printer comparability list](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index), the `HP DeskJet 2130 All-in-one Printer` is supported. Why did you need to install this manually, rather than installing the `hplip` and `hplip-gui` packages from the the official Ubuntu repositories using `apt`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 2):

You can install `hplip` using the following command on Ubuntu 21.04

```
sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui
```

This may not give the latest version. To install latest version, first remove python2 and restart.

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
reboot
```

While running cmake, I got issues about missing dependencies. Install these dependencies with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install libavahi-core-dev
```

Then download the installer from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip and run it. Use one of the embedded script or the tarball.

Comment: none of them work.
both of them have errors the HP Download package wants a non supported phyton package and via apt you get:
error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality. because the setup does not find the models.dat very annoying